# How to parse complex XML with attribute as a condition in c#

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing

I'm a beginner with XML parsing. And I tried many examples to read this XML and parse only needed things. I want to know which one would be a better option whether XML or Linq.
This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AcSmDatabase clsid="g2162C6B6-0CE4-40E8-912B-46F59DFDF826" ID="g9FF6C26D-885D-4C19-8B8C-69C43567DDED">
  <AcSmProp propname="DbFingerPrint" vt="8">gB81BEEBE-7D91-4E80-BC96-A4E7FF6EDCF7</AcSmProp>
  <AcSmSheetSet clsid="gB20534F2-0978-418C-8D14-2E6928A077ED" ID="g5842FAA3-9006-470A-97D6-58BA675533B0" propname="SheetSet" vt="13">
    <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">TestSSet</AcSmProp>
    <AcSmFileReference clsid="g6BF87AE7-1BEC-4BDB-98BB-5B91F7772793" ID="g50C8E86D-E25F-4EFE-966F-E676C90C1551" propname="NewSheetLocation" vt="13">
      <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.</AcSmProp>
    </AcSmFileReference>
    <AcSmProjectPointLocations clsid="gE40EA246-BAB4-4907-81A5-511EA30C16FD" ID="g6F754DE4-5BC0-4159-A068-A961CFEBE56C" propname="ProjectPointLocations" vt="13" />
    <AcSmProp propname="PromptForDwt" vt="2">-1</AcSmProp>
    <AcSmPublishOptions clsid="gF57F96E7-0F16-4DC9-8F09-52F7BB389AB6" ID="g0510F544-063F-4BC7-B063-557E498985EF" propname="PublishOptions" vt="13">
      <AcSmProp propname="DwfType" vt="2">-1</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="EplotFormat" vt="3">2</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="PromptForName" vt="2">-1</AcSmProp>
    </AcSmPublishOptions>
    <AcSmResources clsid="g3F0FAF10-09DE-4EBA-AED1-C4E4D6FECF5D" ID="gB7FF57F8-A338-4933-B166-CA7D92FE0F30" propname="Resources" vt="13" />
    <AcSmSheetSelSets clsid="g444780B8-6527-43A8-8DC4-FAB41B7E48BB" ID="g29ED9C5D-7A76-470C-9C03-6DA6B6EEE8B5" propname="SheetSelSets" vt="13" />
    <AcSmViewCategories clsid="g021730DF-5BEA-48E9-BC7A-35087A674FD0" ID="g2497A15A-A6EA-452C-9699-156310CA84B1" propname="ViewCategories" vt="13">
      <AcSmViewCategory clsid="g4AEA81ED-C24F-477B-A534-EA69220A276A" ID="g120BB674-4D16-49E4-9288-05D67A447621">
        <AcSmCalloutBlockReferences clsid="g67C52FE4-0A6B-4C82-A4CC-5E68537747B0" ID="g82F94574-0931-48A0-8C3A-27DE3FE3C9D3" propname="CalloutBlocks" vt="13" />
      </AcSmViewCategory>
    </AcSmViewCategories>
    <AcSmSubset clsid="g076D548F-B0F5-4FE1-B35D-7F7B73B8D322" ID="g6843B16C-93BA-46AD-B965-3E7277F61AFB">
      <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8">New subset added</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">SubsetOne</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmFileReference clsid="g6BF87AE7-1BEC-4BDB-98BB-5B91F7772793" ID="gE52BEABE-8B71-4BA7-9D1B-210411A6B2B7" propname="NewSheetLocation" vt="13">
        <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.</AcSmProp>
      </AcSmFileReference>
      <AcSmProp propname="PromptForDwt" vt="2">-1</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmSheet clsid="g16A07941-BC15-4D48-A880-9D5A211D5065" ID="g1FC4F6B2-9619-4AA7-84FD-F4AFA750CC73">
        <AcSmAcDbLayoutReference clsid="g94910E94-4FCA-427C-B6ED-2EC9E1C900C7" ID="g8F448CF5-BB6A-4952-8974-4DFED14A6F2F" propname="Layout" vt="13">
          <AcSmProp propname="AcDbHandle" vt="8">1E</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14\1 layoutrenamesheet.dwg</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">layoutOne</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.\1 layoutrenamesheet.dwg</AcSmProp>
        </AcSmAcDbLayoutReference>
        <AcSmProp propname="Number" vt="8">1</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmSheetViews clsid="gF40F931B-64BC-4B90-9FC8-A11A77D6815B" ID="g825D8B24-6B23-453D-96A4-93905CEE9B7E" propname="SheetViews" vt="13" />
        <AcSmProp propname="Title" vt="8">layoutrenamesheet</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionNumber" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionDate" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="IssuePurpose" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Category" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      </AcSmSheet>
    </AcSmSubset>
    <AcSmSubset clsid="g076D548F-B0F5-4FE1-B35D-7F7B73B8D322" ID="gCFD0B39D-FF06-4C0C-913F-8BC9E2122BCC">
      <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8">New subset added</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">SubsetTwo</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmFileReference clsid="g6BF87AE7-1BEC-4BDB-98BB-5B91F7772793" ID="gA9769EC1-D268-4F19-B8D3-3B30E394A594" propname="NewSheetLocation" vt="13">
        <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.</AcSmProp>
      </AcSmFileReference>
      <AcSmProp propname="PromptForDwt" vt="2">-1</AcSmProp>
    </AcSmSubset>
      <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8">New subset added</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">SubsetThree</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmFileReference clsid="g6BF87AE7-1BEC-4BDB-98BB-5B91F7772793" ID="g3EFE83CC-A0D0-45FC-832C-E4CF1ACAACAD" propname="NewSheetLocation" vt="13">
        <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.</AcSmProp>
      </AcSmFileReference>
      <AcSmProp propname="PromptForDwt" vt="2">-1</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmSheet clsid="g16A07941-BC15-4D48-A880-9D5A211D5065" ID="gD5BD538E-95F5-4F8C-B240-75A7181273B3">
        <AcSmAcDbLayoutReference clsid="g94910E94-4FCA-427C-B6ED-2EC9E1C900C7" ID="gC30A57FC-2D0B-4436-AA00-12470B432686" propname="Layout" vt="13">
          <AcSmProp propname="AcDbHandle" vt="8">1E</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14\3 sheet1.dwg</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">layoutThree</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.\3 sheet1.dwg</AcSmProp>
        </AcSmAcDbLayoutReference>
        <AcSmProp propname="Number" vt="8">3</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmSheetViews clsid="gF40F931B-64BC-4B90-9FC8-A11A77D6815B" ID="g704A6223-E755-4662-B108-843AB35BF838" propname="SheetViews" vt="13" />
        <AcSmProp propname="Title" vt="8">sheet1</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionNumber" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionDate" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="IssuePurpose" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Category" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      </AcSmSheet>
      <AcSmSheet clsid="g16A07941-BC15-4D48-A880-9D5A211D5065" ID="gE88F3C2A-92EE-4CF9-BBE8-F2ED4ED2433E">
        <AcSmAcDbLayoutReference clsid="g94910E94-4FCA-427C-B6ED-2EC9E1C900C7" ID="g46C592DC-86D8-4173-974C-36633B209CBB" propname="Layout" vt="13">
          <AcSmProp propname="AcDbHandle" vt="8">1E</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14\4 sheet2.dwg</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">layoutFour</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.\4 sheet2.dwg</AcSmProp>
        </AcSmAcDbLayoutReference>
        <AcSmProp propname="Number" vt="8">4</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmSheetViews clsid="gF40F931B-64BC-4B90-9FC8-A11A77D6815B" ID="g9F4A3151-F82D-4D86-9A76-F405001A2383" propname="SheetViews" vt="13" />
        <AcSmProp propname="Title" vt="8">sheet2</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="IssuePurpose" vt="8">koluppu</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionNumber" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionDate" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Category" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      </AcSmSheet>
      <AcSmSheet clsid="g16A07941-BC15-4D48-A880-9D5A211D5065" ID="gD0451C82-D493-43CC-A6CA-87642FA96DA9">
        <AcSmAcDbLayoutReference clsid="g94910E94-4FCA-427C-B6ED-2EC9E1C900C7" ID="gED7DCAB4-45BC-43C8-A226-DF3842FB9B8D" propname="Layout" vt="13">
          <AcSmProp propname="AcDbHandle" vt="8">1E</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14\5 sheet3.dwg</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">layoutFive</AcSmProp>
          <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.\5 sheet3.dwg</AcSmProp>
        </AcSmAcDbLayoutReference>
        <AcSmProp propname="Number" vt="8">5</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmSheetViews clsid="gF40F931B-64BC-4B90-9FC8-A11A77D6815B" ID="gD211C7F5-81FE-4B46-8083-218D322165E4" propname="SheetViews" vt="13" />
        <AcSmProp propname="Title" vt="8">sheet3</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionNumber" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="RevisionDate" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="IssuePurpose" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Category" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      </AcSmSheet>
    </AcSmSubset>
    <AcSmSheet clsid="g16A07941-BC15-4D48-A880-9D5A211D5065" ID="g611F8282-3FAA-42B5-8CBC-614DD0713570">
      <AcSmAcDbLayoutReference clsid="g94910E94-4FCA-427C-B6ED-2EC9E1C900C7" ID="g90BAA810-F2F2-4CED-82C4-89E86943CFBB" propname="Layout" vt="13">
        <AcSmProp propname="AcDbHandle" vt="8">1E</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="FileName" vt="8">D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14\6 t1.dwg</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Name" vt="8">layoutSix</AcSmProp>
        <AcSmProp propname="Relative_FileName" vt="8">.\6 t1.dwg</AcSmProp>
      </AcSmAcDbLayoutReference>
      <AcSmProp propname="Number" vt="8">6</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmSheetViews clsid="gF40F931B-64BC-4B90-9FC8-A11A77D6815B" ID="g99805F55-4F5C-4121-A2D3-F94F5549B668" propname="SheetViews" vt="13" />
      <AcSmProp propname="Title" vt="8">t1</AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="Desc" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="RevisionNumber" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="RevisionDate" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="IssuePurpose" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
      <AcSmProp propname="Category" vt="8"> </AcSmProp>
    </AcSmSheet>
  </AcSmSheetSet>
</AcSmDatabase>
```

The structure of this XML:
**In words:**
SheetSet is a Project, it may contain any no folders(subsets) and Sheets.
A folder(subset) may contain any no of folders(subsets) and sheets.
And Each sheet should have a property named layout.
I want to get the layout properties alone.

**Output I need:**
LayoutLocation., LayoutName., LayoutTitle.,
which would be in any set format(List, DataTable, whatever.,)
"D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14\1 layoutrenamesheet.dwg"., layoutOne., layoutrenamesheet., 
"D:\Thyagu\AutoCAD14\6 t1.dwg"., layoutSix., t1.,

I did R&D on this for so much of time, but still I didn't get the solution for this.

The C# Code I Used:

```html
XmlNodeList xmlSubSetList = Doc.SelectNodes("AcSmDatabase/AcSmSheetSet/AcSmSubset");
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlSubSetList)
            {
                XmlNode xmlFolder = node;
                XmlNodeList xmlSheets = xmlFolder.SelectNodes("AcSmSheet");
                foreach (XmlNode xmlSheetProp in xmlSheets) //{ }
                {
                    XmlNodeList xmlEle = xmlSheetProp.SelectNodes("AcSmAcDbLayoutReference");
                    foreach (XmlNode xmlLastNode in xmlEle)
                    {
                        XmlNodeList xmlFinalLoop = xmlLastNode.SelectNodes(".//AcSmProp");
                        foreach (XmlNode xmlEnd in xmlFinalLoop)
                        {
                            if (xmlEnd.Attributes["propname"].Value == "FileName")
                            {
                                string strFileLocation = xmlEnd.InnerText.ToString();
                                XmlNode xmlParentParentNode = xmlEnd.ParentNode.ParentNode;
                                XmlNodeList xmlLayoutTitleLoop = xmlParentParentNode.SelectNodes(".//AcSmProp");
                                foreach (XmlNode xmlTitle in xmlLayoutTitleLoop)
                                {
                                    if (xmlTitle.Attributes["propname"].Value == "Title")
                                    {
                                        string strTitle = xmlTitle.InnerText.ToString();
                                        ListOfSheetNames += strTitle + "-";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
```

But the Location of "AcSmSheet" tag is not standard.
 It will change dynamically depending on the end-user format he describing while they are creating.
Only thing is Sheets always start with "AcSmSheet" tag.
So that I can't able to access the Sheets which is under the subfolder of any subfolder.

Thanks,

Comment: You added only XML. Please add your C# code. Otherwise its not clear what is your problem with parsing

Comment: It's not clear how far your research took you. I'd *definitely* suggest using LINQ to XML... but it's not easy to understand how your sample XML (which is probably longer than we really need just as an example) maps to the expected output. If you always know the element names and the values of `propname` that you're trying to extract, the rest is fairly straightforward.

Comment: LayoutTitle comes from which AcSmProp element?

Comment: Layout Title Comes from this tag.                             <AcSmProp propname="Title" vt="8">t1</AcSmProp>

Comment: Now, problem is, I can't able to access the Sheets which is under a subfolder inside any subfolder.

Comment: Using the Descendants method you can access all the Sheet node, irrespective of their location in the XML tree. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to traverse XML documents and perform complicated queries on them is `Linq-to-XML`.

Using this statement:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"somePath\myXMLFile.xml");
```

you can load into an `XDocument` the whole XML tree structure.

You can then use `Descendants` method in order to get ***all*** `AcSmSheet` elements contained in the XML document, ***irrespective of their location***. Having this you can perform the following query to return the required result set:

```
var results = from sheet in xdoc.Descendants("AcSmSheet")
              select new
              {
                  LayoutLocation = sheet.Descendants("AcSmProp")
                                        .Where(t => t.Attribute("propname")
                                        .Value == "FileName")
                                        .First().Value,
                  LayoutName = sheet.Descendants("AcSmProp")
                                    .Where(t => t.Attribute("propname")
                                    .Value == "Name")
                                    .First().Value,
                  LayoutTitle = sheet.Descendants("AcSmProp")
                                     .Where(t => t.Attribute("propname")
                                     .Value == "Title")
                                     .First().Value                                  
              };
```

Using the XML excerpt provided in the OP the above query yields the following results:

```
[0] = { LayoutLocation = "D:\\Thyagu\\AutoCAD14\\1 layoutrenamesheet.dwg", LayoutName = "layoutOne", LayoutTitle = "layoutrenamesheet" }
[1] = { LayoutLocation = "D:\\Thyagu\\AutoCAD14\\3 sheet1.dwg", LayoutName = "layoutThree", LayoutTitle = "sheet1" }
[2] = { LayoutLocation = "D:\\Thyagu\\AutoCAD14\\4 sheet2.dwg", LayoutName = "layoutFour", LayoutTitle = "sheet2" }
[3] = { LayoutLocation = "D:\\Thyagu\\AutoCAD14\\5 sheet3.dwg", LayoutName = "layoutFive", LayoutTitle = "sheet3" }
[4] = { LayoutLocation = "D:\\Thyagu\\AutoCAD14\\6 t1.dwg", LayoutName = "layoutSix", LayoutTitle = "t1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking into converting the XML into a delimited text document, without performing any extensive added logic, I would actually recommend you on using XSLT to parse the XML file.

Using this instead of parsing your XML in code (using XMLDocument,XPath, Linq or any other solution), gives you the added benefit of re-configuring your parsing without recompiling your code, simply by changing the XSLT mapping file used.

In case you are new to XSLT, here a few articles to start you up:

[Using XSLT in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742(v=vs.110).aspx) &
[Writing XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)

Also please note that the XML content you provided is broken, there is one excess "***AcSmSubset***" closing tag